# Login to web site using Perl library Selenium::Remote::Driver v1.28

Tags: perl, selenium

The simple `send_keys` method has been removed from the v1.28 version of
[`Selenium::Remote::Driver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver)
and replaced with `send_keys_to_active_element`.  I'm now unable to log in to a web site with username and password fields.

Below is the previous library methods.
How can I do the same using the v1.28 version?

```
$sel->wait_for_element_present("name=username");                                                    
$sel->type("name=username", $username);
$sel->type("name=password", $password);
$sel->submit("name=Login");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused with the various CPAN modules. The code you show uses methods from
[`WWW::Selenium`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Selenium),
but it has no `send_keys` because there is `type` instead which you use in your code

[`Selenium::Remote::WebElement`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::WebElement)
has a `send_keys` method. If you want to use this module then you need to call one of the `find_element` methods
from
[`Selenium::Remote::Driver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver)
to get a `WebElement` object, and call `send_keys`on that. You will also need the
[`Selenium::Waiter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Waiter)
module to wait for given elements to appear

Something like this should work, but there is insufficient detail in your question for me to write a full demonstration, and I have no way of testing Perl code at present

```
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Waiter qw/ wait_until /;

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new(...);

$driver->get(...);

wait_until({
    $driver->find_element_by_name('username')
})->send_keys($username);

$driver->find_element_by_name('password')->send_keys($password);

$driver->find_element_by_name('Login')->submit;
```